# make link on SWF File to another HTML

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

I am having a problem with SWF File. I have a SWF File on my HTML page and i need to link it to another HTML i used    but the anchor is not working. Any one can help me. How to link a SWF file.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use SWFObject to add a *flashvar* like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.targetURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("myflashmovie.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

That being said, this is assuming that within your Flash movie, it is coded such that the Flash movie is expecting that *flashvar* and using that link to the stipulated URL

In AS 2.0 it would be:

```
getURL(_root.targetURL);
```

In AS 3.0 it would be:

```
var flashvars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var linkURL = flashvars['targetURL']; 
var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest (linkURL);
navigateToURL(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it. Here is what I did:

1. made a clear png graphic the same size as the area you want your flash video to be in
2. make a new layer (div tag) over the flash video - you must be in standard view to edit layers - layers are like tables: they hold images,text, etc.(beware: if you are using tables, the div tag will float over the table when you resize your browser)
3. add the blank png into the new layer
4. link the blank png using the properties window in dreamweaver!
5. Within your object tag that holds the flash object add this line of code . This sets the background of your flash movie to transparent and allows the png layer to be placed above it. If you still need your flash movie to have a background, just create a colored box in your flash movie and use it as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a blog post about how to navigate to a url through flash:

[Linking to url in action script 3](http://www.graphicmania.net/linking-to-url-in-action-script-3-writen-by-rafiq-elmansy/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also add javascript command but onclick does not work because it is already preset.
by using onmouseover command will do the trick but do you want to do it that way? if so

```
`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" onMouseOver="parent.location='http://www.mysite.com'"> <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="movie" value="101.swf" /></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

onmouseup do the job like(not exactly the same) click, It works for me. because onclick does not work there.

```
object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" **onmouseup="document.location='http://www.mysite.com';"**> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="movie" value="101.swf" />
</object>
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately, click on the [orange question-mark](http://i.imgur.com/GjKAG.png) in the question or answer text box for help. Thanks!